# Cannot restore SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using C# Windows Forms to restore a SQL Server database and the following error occurred:

> Restore cannot process database ‘book_store’ because it is in used by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when preforming this operation. Restore DATABASE terminating abnormally non-qualified transaction are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion:100%.

Code:

```
String sql = "ALTER DATABASE Book_store SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
sql += "RESTORE DATABASE Book_store FROM DISK = '" + textboxpath.text + "' WITH REPLACE, STATES = 5";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The error is actually telling you what to do here, don't connect to the database you are restoring, connect to `[master]`, or put `USE [master];` at the start of your query.

Comment: I am actually quite scared here. You are restoring a database in code and the sql you have is wide open to sql injection. It is a huge red flag to me seeing a database restore in dotnet code. This is a DBA type of task, not something that should be done regularly. Maybe in a utility but even then...and just grabbing the text from a textbox and executing is a recipe for very bad things to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are connected to the database you're trying to set to single user.  Try this.

`String sql = “USE master; ALTER DATABASE Book_store SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE”;`

Comment: Not sure if this could do anything if you still open the connection with database setting pointing to the same database you want to restore. The problem is in the connectionstring not on the query

Comment: @Steve Nope, your statement is incorrect.The "use" statement will have the same effect as changing the connection string parameter. The current database of a connection is not fixed at the time the connection is established; it can be freely changed during its lifetime.

Comment: I should tell the truth. Never used the _use_ statement inside an application. Glad to know.

Comment: @Steve it is great for when you need to communicate with multiple databases but still want to take advantage of .NET's connection pooling (The pools are keyed by the connection string)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for restoring the database:

```
using (sqlcon)
               {
                   string UseMaster = "USE master";
                   OdbcCommand UseMasterCommand = new OdbcCommand(UseMaster, sqlcon);
                   UseMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   // The below query will rollback any transaction which is
                   running on that database and brings SQL Server database in a single user mode.
                   string Alter1 = @"ALTER DATABASE
                   [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate";
                   OdbcCommand Alter1Cmd = new OdbcCommand(Alter1, sqlcon);
                   Alter1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   // The below query will restore database file from disk where backup was taken ....
                   string Restore = @"RESTORE DATABASE
                   [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] FROM DISK = N'" +
                   backUpPath + @"' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
                   OdbcCommand RestoreCmd = new OdbcCommand(Restore, sqlcon);
                   RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   // the below query change the database back to multiuser
                   string Alter2 = @"ALTER DATABASE
                   [" + DatabaseFullPath + "] SET Multi_User";
                   OdbcCommand Alter2Cmd = new OdbcCommand(Alter2, sqlcon);
                   Alter2Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
               }
```